# If it falls within a div 

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

**Is there a way to detect if an element is currently located within a div?**

I have scrolling vertical menu. I set the height of the navigation div and then overflow:hidden so I only see a few of the links at a time.

So, I click a graphic at the bottom of the navigation to move the links down. I have another graphic at the top to get the opposite effect.

But, I can't find a reliable way to stopping the animation. So the movement keeps going way past the first and last menu links.

You can see the problem at http://test2omniforce.co.uk/test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the current value of the div#content top margin when the buttons are clicked. So for example, the top button's animation should only play if div#content margin-top is less than 0, and the bottom button's animation when the margin-top is greater than -500.

Comment: how do I test for elements margin-top?

Comment: $('div#content').css('margin-top') will give you the top margin.  Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/yCreg/

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question, jQuery offers the [`:has`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo selector for detecting. Looks like

```
if( $('div:has(span)').length )  { }  // true if a div contains a `<span>` node.
```

But I don't think this is your problem. To reliable stop an animation, you can just call [`.stop()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).
Probably like

```
$('div').stop(true,true).animate() // ...
```

The parameters tell jQuery, to clear the current *fx queue* and jump to the end.

Another technique to avoid *multiple executing* of asyncronous effects, is to invoke the [`:animated`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) pseudo selector. With that, you can *detect* if an element currently is animated and if so, do nothing.

```
if( $('div').is(':animated') ) { }  // div is currently animated
```

Comment: The OP's actually having trouble with figuring out whether the content inside that div is going out of the viewport(?). He needs something to figure out whether the top/bottom of the menu is visible before animating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
if ( $('#myElement').closest('div').length > 0 ) {
    // yup, I'm inside a DIV
}
```

You can also plug in a proper jQuery selector inside the `.closest()` function. So to check if an element is inside my scrollable DIV, you can use:

```
$('#myElement').closest('div#myScrollableDiv').length > 0
```